# Arduino - Needs insane amounts of 0's to make LED go for 3 seconds

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I  am doing a project with an arduino to make a bell ring, and when I first tried, it worked how I wanted it to (`wait(Serial.read())`), but now I need to send over 100 `0`'s over the serial port just to make it show for 4 seconds. Here is my Java code:
*prepare for longness*

```
Main.ringBell("100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");

public static void ringBell(String length) throws Exception {
     output.write(length.getBytes());
     output.flush();
}
```

Here is the Arduino sketch:

```
int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if(Serial.available() > 0) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        delay(Serial.read());
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
}
```

Does anyone see a error in my code? If so, please just let me know what's wrong and I'll fix it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not sending one big number to the arduino but several ASCII bytes. The Arduino will see this sequence:

```
49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, ...
```

In each loop it will read one byte and wait for that number of **milliseconds**. 49 or 48 milliseconds are not a long time. So what you have is a constant flicker of the LED which is to fast to see with the eye.

The next thing is: You are sending the bytes in one flush. But the Arduino has only a small internal buffer of 64 byte (see [available](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available) docu). The rest is simply forgotten.

Lets calculate roughly: 64 bytes * (48 ms delay per byte ) is 3072ms. Yes, this sounds plausible.

Next thing would be: `delay` only can handle arguments of type `unsigned long` which is 32 bit which translates to ~4,000,000,000 milliseconds you can wait. Your argument in `Main` is way beyond this limit.

So: The easiest thing is to use `parseInt` instead of `read`. And in `Main` supply only numbers in the range of a positive `int` (0.. 32767). And also do some delays in your `Main` before sending the next `ringBell`.

Comment: It has defiantly improved, but it still does not ring for 8 seconds when I send "8000". I replaced "read()" with "parseInt()" and that is what made the difference, so do you know how to make it run for 8 seconds with "8000"?

Comment: You can store the result of `parseInt` into a variable and print that to the `Serial` stream. Then you can test you code in the Arduino "Serial Monitor" more easily by comparing what has been sent and what has been received.

Comment: @cheese5505 test if your delay function working as should. if it is initialized with wrong clock value then it waits different time then it should by constant ratio. measure the difference ... PS. I do not code for this platform but I am familiar with MCU's